# SQL table only updating on a specific click event, not the other

Tags: vb.net

In code shown below, clicking on the btSave will cause the table to be updated, assuming that some data in vendmast has been changed.  However, clicking on the label lblMyExit will run the code but it will not recognize that vendmast should be updated.   Am very perplexed.  This is the first question I have ever asked.  Hope I am doing it right. Dennis

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click, _
lblMyExit.Click
    CmdBldr.DataAdapter = DA
    CMD.CommandText = SQVEND
    DA.SelectCommand = CMD
    CmdBldr.DataAdapter = DA
    CmdBldr.RefreshSchema()
    DS.Tables("vendmast").Rows(0).EndEdit()
    Try
        DA.Update(DS.Tables("vendmast"))
        DS.Tables("vendmast").AcceptChanges()
    Catch
        Debug.Print("ERROR")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to update TABLE inside app stack memory or do SQL update

Comment: Did you change any data in the datatable between the first and second save?

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do this is to put the update code in a separate method and call it from both event handlers. Six months from now it will be much easier to figure out what is going on when the label is clicked. As to why your code isn't working, is the `lblMyExit.Click` declared `With Events` in the designer code?

I don't have enough information to comment on the actual update code but be aware that database objects usually need to be disposed. It is often a bad idea to declare them outside the method where they are used. The language provides `Using...End Using` blocks to help you manage these objects.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    UpdateDatabase()
End Sub

Private Sub lblMyExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblMyExit.Click
    UpdateDatabase()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDatabase()
    CMD.CommandText = SQVEND
    DA.SelectCommand = CMD
    CmdBldr.DataAdapter = DA
    CmdBldr.RefreshSchema()
    DS.Tables("vendmast").Rows(0).EndEdit()
    Try
        DA.Update(DS.Tables("vendmast"))
        DS.Tables("vendmast").AcceptChanges()
    Catch
        Debug.Print("ERROR")
    End Try
End Sub
```